# Header information is printed in mail body

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

We have a very intermittent problem.
Whenever our client sends out email notification from our system. They also get header information mail body, and this thing is very intermittent. We tried our best to replicate it on our test servers but failed.
This is how the message looks like.

This is just a simple mail

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

body which consist header information. We are using `javax.mail` library to send out emails. This is our sample code.

```
hostName = mailSession.getProperty("mail.smtp.host");
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
msg.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
if (!bcc) {
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
} else {
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, addressTo);
}
msg.setText(reportContent, "UTF-8");
```

One thing more we have set content-type as `text/html` but the header gets printed in the body have `text/plain`

Even small help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please check the Java [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29). setText is a convenience method that sets the given String as this part's content, with a MIME type of "text/plain"

Comment: Yes, use [this setText method](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setText-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) instead.  And make sure the Subject string doesn't contain any newlines.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. Where you able to resolve this ?